# AWS ALB one of IP is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

I setup AWS ALB and point that it domain using aliases recode.Then my website is working fine.But I saw some unreliability.Then I find out below issue.please help me to solve this.

telnet is only working on one IP.

XXX-614383224.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 52.3.50.53
XXX-614383224.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 54.165.84.185

```
ubuntu@app:~$ telnet  52.3.50.53 443
Trying 52.3.50.53...
Connected to 52.3.50.53.
Escape character is '^]'.


ubuntu@app:~$ telnet 54.165.84.185 80
Trying 54.165.84.185..
```

(When I check the same scenario in classic elb it's working fine )

Comment: Was the classic balancer placed in the exact same two subnets as this one?

Comment: yep.issue was one of private subnet without no routes.thanks issue fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VPC does not prevent provisioning of a load balancer on one or more incorrectly-configured subnets, presumably because there are certain scenarios where an unusual configuration might be intended, in limited/special/unusual circumstances.

If at least one of the subnets where the balancer is deployed does not have a default route pointing to your VPC's Internet Gateway `igw-xxxxxxxx` object, this is the behavior you would observe.